# Distribution of weighted data

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

Assume that $x_1, ... , x_n$ is a sample of independent observations.

Classically, the degree of belonging $x_i$ into the random sample is equal to $1$, so all observations are weighted equally.

But in case when each observation is (not independently) weighted $(x_1, w_1),...,(x_n, w_n)$ by $w_i \in [0,1]$ a '*weighted data set*' is derived. Note that the same $x_i$ values might have different weights.

Is there some formula (or at least a definition) for the **distribution of the weigthed data** in terms of the distribution of unweighted (equally weighted) data?

Comment: Is the weights a random variable as well? Dependent on $(x_i)$?

Comment: @MaxFt If you treat $w_1,...,w_n$ as a sample you get another distribution as well.

Comment: Well I could help you write the cdf or density of the randow variable XW. But it will ultimately depend on the joint distribution of X and W. Of course it could be re written using the conditional density of W | X and the density of X (unweighted data) is it what you are looking for? Is it a theoretical problem or based on a dataset?

Comment: @MaxFt I think this is a very fundamental problem which pretty much arises for all measured observations since usually not all obs. are equally trustworthy/important. I dont see how it is related to the joint or cond. probabilities.